# sortedArrayWithSelector and NSDictionnary on iOS

Tags: ios, sorting, compare, nsdictionary

I have an array of NSDictionnary and I would like to sort them by an int value (the key is named "age").
For exemple :

Dic1 : age = 30, sex = male;
Dic2 : age = 24, sex = male;

Array : Dic1, Dic2;

Now with a compare method I would lik to have :

Array : Dic2, Dic1;

I tried lots of things but doesn't work. I as using NSSortDescriptor but it's only available since iOS 4.0 :(

Have you got a solution ?
Thanks !

EDIT :

I wrote a compare method on NSDictionary category :

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareGood:(NSDictionary *)otherObject 
{
    return [[self objectForKey:@"age"] compare:[otherObject objectForKey:@"age"]];
}
```

But I have this crash error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for NSSortDescriptor says:

> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Likewise for the NSMutableArray method `-sortUsingDescriptors:`. You should be able to do this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"age" 
                                                          ascending:YES]
                                                          autorelease];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
```

or, if myArray isn't mutable, do this for the second line:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Comment: sortDescriptorWithKey: ascending: and sortedArrayUsingDescriptor are only available since iOS 4.0. But thx I'm using now sortUsingDescriptors: and initWithKey: ascending:

Comment: Good point -- I've updated the example to use `-initWithKey:ascending:`.